# rsyslogd is not writing to local facilities as per my configuration

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to use rsyslogd to allow me to send syslog messages to any of the local facilities. Here is my configuration:

```
dchappelle@L164:/etc/rsyslog.d$ cat 50-default.conf
#  Default rules for rsyslog.
#
#           For more information see rsyslog.conf(5) and /etc/rsyslog.conf

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
local0.*                /var/log/test-local-facility.log

auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*             /var/log/cron.log
#daemon.*           -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
#lpr.*              -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
#user.*             -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
#mail.info          -/var/log/mail.info
#mail.warn          -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err            /var/log/mail.err

#
# Logging for INN news system.
#
news.crit           /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err            /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice         -/var/log/news/news.notice

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
#*.=debug;\
#   auth,authpriv.none;\
#   news.none;mail.none -/var/log/debug
#*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
#   auth,authpriv.none;\
#   cron,daemon.none;\
#   mail,news.none      -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg                                :omusrmsg:*

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#   news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#   *.=debug;*.=info;\
#   *.=notice;*.=warn   /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
    news.err;\
    *.=debug;*.=info;\
    *.=notice;*.=warn   |/dev/xconsole
dchappelle@L164:/etc/rsyslog.d$
```

Here is my example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        openlog("test", LOG_PID|LOG_CONS, LOG_LOCAL0);
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "This is a test log message for local0");
        closelog();

        return 0;
    }
```

After making the configuration change I restarted the rsyslogd service:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

When I run my example program, the file /var/log/test-local-facility.log is not created. Instead, the syslog message is showing up in /var/log/syslog. I have scoured the bowels of the internets looking for help and no such luck. I even tried running rsyslogd in debug mode and no dice. Anyone out there have any experience here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I manually created the file and changed the permissions/owner/group:

```
dchappelle@L164:/etc/rsyslog.d$ ls -l /var/log/test-local-facility.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 142 Nov  9 18:43 /var/log/test-local-facility.log
```

Now when I run my example program, the log message is showing up as expected. However, it is still being sent to /var/log/syslog as well which is not what I want. How do I prevent it from being sent there?

Comment: You should edit your question to include these details rather than creating answers with more details.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, to get the syslog messages to not go to /var/log/syslog I also had to add a rule to stop processing after it was consumed by a facility:

```
local0.*                /var/log/test-local-facility.log
& stop
```

Need to make sure that this comes before any of the other facility rules. You would think that a simple use case like this would be easy to find examples for. In fact, you would think that the rsyslog docs would clearly cover this particular use case.

Comment: You should edit your question to include these details rather than creating answers with more details